# jQuery Array : Add css class to specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

I have a small problem with this array.

I need to add css class in each key has a value 0 for exemple, this is my essay:

```
var obj = {"test_1":"1","test_2":"1","test_3":"0","test_4":"0","test_5":"0","test_6":"1","test_7":"0"};
$.each( obj, function( key, value ) { 
  alert("key " + key + " has value " + obj[key]);
  if(value = 0) {
    $('#'+ key).addClass('hidden');// hidden only the obj has value = 0
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8TT4p/1636/

Comment: use `==` instead of `=` in your test condition for value

Comment: Done ! 

http://jsfiddle.net/8TT4p/1638/

Thank you very much  Immanuel Valle

Comment: No problem. If this one helped you, kindly check the posted answer below so others can see it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning `0` to variable `value` , which will always return true. Replace it with `if(value==0)` so it will return a boolean value.